# binding threads in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I would like to use a wxThread in my programm. The thread should establish a serial connection via a COM port and should make an event in case the COM port is wrong/the connection was not established. In this case, my main frame should ask the user for another COM port.

As I am not quite sure what would be the best event, I try using `wxThreadEvent`. Now I have a problem dynamically binding the event to a function, as the example I found [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind) does not work for me. This is my code:

WindowsDgpsGUIMain.cpp:

```
WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
 ...
 Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, &onConnectionFailed, wxID_RETRY);
}

void WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onConnectionFailed(wxThreadEvent& event)
{
  ;
}
```

WindowsDgpsGUIMain.h:

```
class WindowsDgpsGUIFrame: public wxFrame
{

    public:

        WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id = -1);
        virtual ~WindowsDgpsGUIFrame();

    private:

        //(*Handlers(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame)
        void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButtonTracksClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButtonPortsClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButtonRewriteConfigClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
        //*)
        void onConnectionFailed(wxThreadEvent& event);
  ...
  }
```

When I try like this I get this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in WindowsDgpsGUI (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\WindowsDgps\WindowsDgpsGUI\WindowsDgpsGUIMain.cpp||In constructor 'WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow*, wxWindowID)':|
D:\WindowsDgps\WindowsDgpsGUI\WindowsDgpsGUIMain.cpp|165|error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onConnectionFailed' [-fpermissive]|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\event.h||In instantiation of 'void wxEventFunctorFunctor<EventTag, Functor>::operator()(wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) [with EventTag = wxEventTypeTag<wxThreadEvent>; Functor = void (WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::*)(wxThreadEvent&)]':|
D:\WindowsDgps\WindowsDgpsGUI\WindowsDgpsGUIMain.cpp|342|required from here|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\event.h|516|error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((wxEventFunctorFunctor<wxEventTypeTag<wxThreadEvent>, void (WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::*)(wxThreadEvent&)>*)this)->wxEventFunctorFunctor<wxEventTypeTag<wxThreadEvent>, void (WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::*)(wxThreadEvent&)>::m_handler (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((wxEventFunctorFunctor<wxEventTypeTag<wxThreadEvent>, void (WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::*)(wxThreadEvent&)>*)this)->wxEventFunctorFunctor<wxEventTypeTag<wxThreadEvent>, void (WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::*)(wxThr|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, as I tried to use the examlpe provided above. Is the `wxID` important for this? I am not quite sure how they work, so I thought using one that describes what I would like to do ist best (as I understand they are just some integer numbers)...

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I know of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890169/wxwidgets-and-threads) thread concerning the same error, though it didn't help me. I tried to change the code accordingly but it does not work and honestly it does not seem to make sense in my case. Though the error is very clear (at least the `ISO++...` part, as I never touched `event.h`) I don't quite get what to make of it.

Comment: Your `Bind` seems to be wrong. You are binding a member function so I guess it should be like `Bind (..., &WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onConnectionFailed, this, ...)`. Altough I am not familiar with the wxWigets Bind.

Comment: You are right @mkaes, I changed it and it works. Thank you.